# Error code 65 when building IOS app on intel xdk

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, construct-2

I have created my game with Construct 2 and exported it to cordova , after that I imported it to intel xdk and I have started work to export to ios , after building I get this error :

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/Robo\ Copter.build/Release-iphoneos/Robo\ Copter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AdMobPlugin.o Robo\ Copter/Plugins/cordova-plugin-ad-admob/AdMobPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: - xcconfig,.../builds/build.2016-11-28.09-05-02.D5Cxki.tmp/cordova_project/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,Robo Copter.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,Robo Copter,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=.../builds/build.2016-11-28.09-05-02.D5Cxki.tmp/cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=.../builds/build.2016-11-28.09-05-02.D5Cxki.tmp/cordova_project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Comment: There should be more to that error message -- can you look at the output above that error message and see if anything else is present?

Comment: My suspicion is code signing is getting in the way. Have you configured code signing in build.json or Xcode?